# Why do I get a foreign key constraint error

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I'm trying to insert values in a table with sql server 2012, but i have this error:

```
The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_Fabricante". 
The conflict occurred in database 
"practica", table "dbo.Fabricantes", column 'Codigo'.
```

I just have two tables available.

this is the code that i use to create the tables

```
create table Fabricantes(
Codigo int identity primary key,
Nombre nvarchar (100) not null)

create table Articulos(
Codigo int identity primary key,
Nombre nvarchar (100) not null,
Precio int,
Fabricante int,
constraint FK_Fabricante foreign key
(Codigo) references Fabricantes (Codigo))
```

Comment: we need information about how the tables relate to each other within the FK.  Which fields is it based on?

Comment: You defined a contraint on a column that is auto-generated. That won't work like that. You have to change yout table definition

Answer (score 5):

If you are trying to `INSERT` a value into the table `Articulos` that does not exist in the table `Fabricantes` then you will get the error.

Since you have a Foreign Key on the `Codigo` field, you have to have the same value in the `Fabricantes`.

See a [non-working demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/5acfc/1).  This demo shows that the value for `Codigo` does not exist in the `Fabricantes` table so it throws the error message. Here is a [working demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/15171/1) which shows that the value is in the table first.

I think you need to redo the tables, slightly anyway.

```
create table Fabricantes
(
  Codigo int identity primary key,
  Nombre nvarchar (100) not null
);

create table Articulos
(
  Codigo int primary key,
  Nombre nvarchar (100) not null,
  Precio int,
  Fabricante int,
  constraint FK_Fabricante foreign key
  (Codigo) references Fabricantes (Codigo)
);
```

You initially had the `Articulos` table with an `identity` set to it but since you have that field as the foreign key, I don't think you should have the `identity` on that table.

Comment: bluefeet beat me to it. Deleting my answer since it's the same as this.

Answer (score 0):

I think your mistake is a wrong foreign key. Based on the look of the tables you should reference Articulo.Fabricante to Fabricante.Codigo like this:

```
create table Fabricantes(
Codigo int identity primary key,
Nombre nvarchar (100) not null)

create table Articulos(
Codigo int identity primary key,
Nombre nvarchar (100) not null,
Precio int,
Fabricante int,
constraint FK_Fabricante foreign key
(Fabricante) references Fabricantes (Codigo))
```

Comment: thanks TToni, it was helpful. right now that I tried to insert new dates on the table Articulos evething was ok. apparently my mistake was in the reference between the two tables